# After installing/activate CCK I do not see the node reference

Tags: drupal, cck

Please answer asap is the last point in the book development part:
p.338 / Drupal 7/
After install / activate CCK I do NOT see Node Reference, ...in form field creation? is needed enable the Node Reference option that comes with the Package,... how, where is this?
Detailed Information “Drupal 7”
•   Language : English
•   Paperback : 370 pages [ 235mm x 191mm ]
•   Release Date : October 2010
•   ISBN : 1849512868
•   ISBN 13 : 978-1-84951-286-2
•   Author : David Mercer

Answer (score 0):

The D7 References module http://drupal.org/project/references may be what you are looking for. There is another, called Relation that appears to be just an API at http://drupal.org/project/Relation. --Joe

Comment: worked, installed the first url...hope no other problem, Thanks!

Comment: @Lse: if this answer is correct and was helpful for you, please click the check mark to accept it. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work